# Shuffling objects in JSON ( AngularJS)

Tags: json, angularjs, html, random

I want my questions to be shown in random order. I did it, but it doesn't work properly, sometimes it doesn't loop through all objects and stops and etc.

```
 $scope.move = function (direction) {
    var position = $scope.allData.indexOf($scope.currentQ);
    $scope.currentQ = $scope.allData[position + direction];
};

$http.get("js/json/questions.json").then(function(response){
    $scope.allData = response.data;
    $scope.currentQ = $scope.allData[Math.floor(Math.random() * response.data.length)];
});

$scope.answerClick = function(index){
    $scope.clicks++;

    if(index === $scope.currentQ.answer){
        $scope.score++;
        $scope.rightwrong = "Right";
        $('.right-wrong').css("color", "green");
    }
    else{
        $scope.rightwrong = "Wrong";
        $('.right-wrong').css("color", "red");
    }

    if($scope.clicks === 4){
        resultService.score = $scope.score;
        $location.path('/finish');
    }

    $scope.move(+1);
};
```

Here is the whole app: http://plnkr.co/edit/wTQHOz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `move` method you can get outside the range of the array. Make it wrap around if you move before the first or after the last question:

```
$scope.currentQ = $scope.allData[(position + direction + $scope.allData.length) % $scope.allData.length];
```

Comment: Can you explain what you just did step by step, actually this part "% $scope.allData.length"? By the way, it works great, so thanks for the solution. And can you help me with one more thing, I have commented part in my "quizController" - countdown timer. It doesn't work like it has to, can you give me some advice about that?

Comment: @Alik: The `%` modulo operator returns the reminder of a division with the second operand. The effect in this case is that it wraps around from zero when the index grows outside the array. The added length inside the parenthesis is to make sure that the value doesn't get negative if you call the function with a -1 direction. When you call `countDowner` from the `setTimeout`, it will be called as a regular function, not as a method of the `$scope` object. Use `$timeout(function(){ $scope.countDowner(); }, 1000);` to call it as a method.